# Any tutorial for developing spoken dialogue system in prolog?

Tags: prolog, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I'm new in Dialogue Management Systems, and I'm try to figure out how to implement one.
I would like to implement a human-machine ***spoken dialogue system*** in a context of bar, which takes as input a text phrase from the user (a request for a given product: chips, cola, water, coffee, etc.) and return as output the corresponding response (Beyond the action, but this doesn't matter).

An example of conversation I would like to reach:

U: Hi, how are you?

S: Hey there. I'm good. How may I help you?

U: I would like to have a coffee and a Croissant with jam"

S: Sure. Here your order!

U: Thank you! bye.

S: Thank to you, too. Have a good day!

That is, rigth now I would just a simple dialogue between them about order at bars.

I was wondering if someone know some tutorial about how to implement a dialogue system, preferably in Prolog.
Anyway, any other language is good for me to at least understand how such systems are implemented.

P.s. I searched on Internet, but I found a lot of material that has confused me and none of them makes an example of how to implement a dialogue system.
Finaly I just want it to be as a software on my PC (not a web application or similar).

Thank you!

Comment: You probably realize it yourself, but Prolog's top level is already quite good at having a "dialogue" with the user. Can you give a concrete example of what functionality you expect, at the very least? (as it stands, it is a small wonder that your question has not been closed as "too broad" or "opinion-based".

Comment: Check out **The Craft of Prolog**. In it, Richard O'Keefe shows how develop a subset of such an interaction. Also notice his clean representation, which makes it possible to use the predicates in several directions.

Comment: Ok, what I aspect the program have to do is to handle a simple dialogue with a user requesting for something at bar (for example, a cola, or a coffee with croissant, etc.) but the system could even to handle the phrases off the topic to return on his own way and fulfill the order.

Answer (score 1):

[ELIZA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) it's the prototypical chatbot.

It doesn't really 'understand' the syntactical structure of the dialog, but could be a good start.

A very [simple example](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/eliza.pl) is in SWISH. Here is some code sleeping on my HD (IIRC, it's from Clocksin - Mellish, ported to SWI-Prolog).

```
eliza :-
    write('? '), read_word_list(Input), eliza(Input), !.

eliza([bye]) :-
    write('Goodbye. I hope I have helped you'), nl.
eliza(Input) :-
    pattern(Stimulus, Response),
    match(Stimulus, Dictionary, Input),
    match(Response, Dictionary, Output),
    reply(Output),
    !, eliza.

match([N|Pattern], Dictionary, Target) :-
    integer(N), lookup(N, Dictionary, LeftTarget),
    append(LeftTarget, RightTarget, Target),
    match(Pattern, Dictionary, RightTarget).
match([Word | Pattern], Dictionary, [Word | Target]) :-
    atom(Word), match(Pattern, Dictionary, Target).
match([], _Dictionary, []).

pattern([i,am,1],[how,long,have,you,been,1,'?']).
pattern([1,you,2,me],[what,makes,you,think,i,2,you,'?']).
pattern([i,like,1],[does,anyone,else,in,your,family,like,1,'?']).
pattern([i,feel,1],[do,you,often,feel,that,way,'?']).
pattern([1,X,2],[can,you,tell,me,more,about,your,X,'?']) :- important(X).
pattern([1],[please,go,on]).

important(father).
important(mother).
important(son).
important(sister).
important(brother).
important(daughter).

reply([Head | Tail]) :-
    write(Head), write(' '), reply(Tail).
reply([]) :- nl.

lookup(Key, [(Key, Value) | _Dict], Value).
lookup(Key, [(Key1, _Val1) | Dictionary], Value) :-
    Key \= Key1, lookup(Key, Dictionary, Value).

read_word_list(Ws) :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Cs),
    atom_codes(A, Cs),
    tokenize_atom(A, Ws).
```

*edit* answering to comment...

Well, that code has been written by Prolog masters, not me :) So, we should try to *understand* it... Those 2 clauses implement an 'incremental dictionary' with an *incomplete data structure*. They bind arbitrary phrases between Stimulus and Response, and are the key to such compact coding of ELIZA (the original program was not so simple, though...). To follow the usage, Prolog debugging is a possibility:

```
?- leash(-all),spy(lookup).

?- eliza.
? i am happy
 * Call: (12) lookup(1, _G4620, _G4621)
 * Exit: (12) lookup(1, [(1, _G4616)|_G4613], _G4616)
 * Call: (15) lookup(1, [(1, [happy])|_G4613], _G4645)
 * Exit: (15) lookup(1, [(1, [happy])|_G4613], [happy])
how long have you been happy ? 

? i think you hate me
 * Call: (14) lookup(1, _G4821, _G4822)
 * Exit: (14) lookup(1, [(1, _G4817)|_G4814], _G4817)
 * Call: (16) lookup(2, [(1, [i, think])|_G4814], _G4834)
 * Call: (17) lookup(2, _G4814, _G4834)
 * Exit: (17) lookup(2, [(2, _G4829)|_G4826], _G4829)
 * Exit: (16) lookup(2, [(1, [i, think]),  (2, _G4829)|_G4826], _G4829)
 * Call: (19) lookup(2, [(1, [i, think]),  (2, [hate])|_G4826], _G4858)
 * Call: (20) lookup(2, [(2, [hate])|_G4826], _G4858)
 * Exit: (20) lookup(2, [(2, [hate])|_G4826], [hate])
 * Exit: (19) lookup(2, [(1, [i, think]),  (2, [hate])|_G4826], [hate])
what makes you think i hate you ? 
...
```

You can see that the tail of the association list is free on exit, so the Dictionary is extended as needed. A clever usage of incomplete data structures. See chapter 15 of 'The art of Prolog'

Comment: May you explain me what do you mean with the rule lookup/3 ?